# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code editor used to work fine but suddenly I get the 500 Internal Server Error when I try to open the https://code.earthengine.google.com/ webpage!

I tried to remove the cache and cookies but still no luck!

Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Earth Engine, and should be fixed now.

For future reference: whenever you see a 500 error, it's not something *you* need to fix, so GIS Stack Exchange isn't the best place to ask about it; please follow the [bug reporting advice](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#report_a_bug) and file a report on Earth Engine's issue tracker.

But thanks for saying something anyway — we caught it faster because of your report.